# Metric space continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

> Consider $R^2$ with the metric
> $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) =|x_1−y_1|+ 2|x_2−y_2|  ∀(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)∈R^2$
> Let $f:R^2 \rightarrow R$ be the function defined by $f(x_1,x_2) =x_{2}^1+x_{2}^2 \ ∀(x_1,x_2)∈R^2$.

Q: Prove  that  the  function f,  defined  from  (R2,d)  onto R with  the  usual  metric,  is  a continuous function at any given point $(a_1,a_2)∈R^2.$

I've started with this:

given any $a \in R^2$ and given any $\epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \ s.t. \ 
d_y(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ whenever $d_x(x,a) < \delta$

$d_x(x,a) = |x_1 - a_1| + 2|x_2 - a_2| ( < \delta)$
$d_y(x,a) = |x_1^2 + x_2^2 - a_1^2 - a_2^2|$

and then by triangle inequality:

$d_y(x,a) \leq |x_1^2 -a_1^2| - | x_2^2- a_2^2|$

now my question is I haven't got too much idea how to relate those two to get into a form to show it is continuous.

If someone could help

Thank you

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "$d_x$ and $d_y$? The metric on $\Bbb R^2$ is just called "$d$". You defined it just above. There is no $x$ there. The metric on $\Bbb R$ is usually just denoted by $|u - v|$. If you want to call it $d_y$, then you need to say that $d_y(u, v) = |u - v|$. (2) In no case is $d_y(x,a) = |x_1^2 + x_2^2 - a_1^2 - a_2^2|$. $d_y$ is defined on real numbers, and $x, a$ are points in $\Bbb R^2$, not real numbers. It is $d_y(f(x), f(y))$ that would be equal to that expression.

Comment: (3) The triangle inequality says $d_y(f(x), f(a)) \le |x_1^2 - a_1^2| \color{red}+|x_2^2 - a_2^2|$, not minus. (4) "given any $a \in R^2$ and given any $\epsilon > 0\ \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $d_y(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$ whenever $d_x(x,a) < \delta$" is what you are trying to get to, not where you start.